# Merging tags [bit.ly] and [bitly]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Both [bit.ly](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bit.ly) and [bitly](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitly) tags refer to the same thing, the [bit.ly](https://bitly.com/) URL shortening service. They should be merged, since there is no difference between them.

[Qs tagged bit.ly](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bit.ly)
[Qs tagged bitly](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The merge is complete with [bit.ly](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bit.ly) as the master tag and [bitly](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitly) as a synonym.